# How can I unit test this action with Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

**This action does several things, but I don't know where to start with Moq, newbie here.**

```
        [Authorization.AppAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Form()
    {
        // Create a new Supplier request form
        StoreRequestViewModel requestForm = new StoreRequestViewModel();
        requestForm.OwnerGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        // Keep in mind the request form ids
        this.Session[requestForm.OwnerSessionCacheKey] = requestForm as IRequestFormViewModel;

        SetupContext();

        return View("IndexForm", requestForm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First up, you will need to mock the `ControllerContext` for this controller instance. That lets you set up the container for `Session` that you will need.

Other than that, the code snippet is pretty testable already, assuming `SetupContext` doesnt do anything untoward.

You simply take the `ActionResult`, conver to `ViewResult`, and then check the `ViewResult.ViewData.Model` property (converting to `StoreRequestViewModel`) and test the properties.